# Style JSON to html and css

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, json

I am making a job hiring page in which I am taking the values from a JSON file. but in job description I want it to have line breaks and style as given there. but everything comes in one single line. I tried adding both `<br>` and `\n` but doesn't work

.Json file

```
{
  "job1": {
    "title": "Job title 1",
    "type": "Full Time",
    "tech": ["stack1", "tech", "abc", "xyz"],
    "discription": "Lorem ipsum 2 <br> \n dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam id voluptatum,  <br> \n consequatur quos corrupti harum magnam architecto, cumque beatae iste tempore natus voluptates iure dicta aliquid explicabo quaerat facere aperiam."
  },
  "job2": {
    "title": "Job Title 2",
    "type": "Part Time",
    "tech": ["JavaScript", "CSS"],
    "discription": "Lorem ipsum 2 dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam id voluptatum, consequatur quos corrupti harum magnam architecto, cumque beatae iste tempore natus voluptates iure dicta aliquid explicabo quaerat facere aperiam."
  },
}
```

Hirings.js (I have dynamically created jobs using a function. here is the description part)

```
import Hidings from "./Hirings.json";

// function

      <div className="job-discription">
        <p>Discription:</p>
        <p>{Hirings[job].discription}</p>
      </div>

// further code
```

The output i am getting is

```
Description:

Lorem ipsum 2 <br> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam id voluptatum, <br> consequatur quos corrupti harum magnam architecto, cumque beatae iste tempore natus voluptates iure dicta aliquid explicabo quaerat facere aperiam.
```

[image]

Expected Output

```
Description:

Lorem ipsum 2 
 dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam id voluptatum, 
 consequatur quos corrupti harum magnam architecto, cumque beatae iste tempore natus voluptates iure dicta aliquid explicabo quaerat facere aperiam.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Try this:

```
     <div className="job-discription">
        <p>Discription:</p>
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: Hirings[job].discription}} />
      </div>
```

Comment: will i have to use `div` for that of it would work for `p` too?

Comment: yes,  `<p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: Hirings[job].discription}} />`